# How to add a icon to the top right of each rectangle in Zoomable Partition Layout in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am a novice at D3 and am trying to modify the Zoomable Partition Layout found here: (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1005873).

I need to add an icon to the top-right of each rectangle, but I am not sure which part of the example code to edit and how?

Does anyone know how I can implement this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that by icon you mean image. You can do this with the following code.

```
rect = rect
  .data(partition(d3.entries(root)[0]))
  .enter();
rect.append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
  .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.dx); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.dy); })
  .attr("fill", function(d) { return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).key); })
  .on("click", clicked);
rect.append("image")
  .attr("xlink:href", "foo.jpg")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x) + x(d.dx) - imageWidth; })
  .attr("width", imageWidth)
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
  .attr("height", imageHeight);
```

See [here](http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/8325413) for a demo.

Comment: Thanks so much Lars, I will try this out and let you know if it is working! Appreciate it!

Comment: I'll add a demo as soon as github is back up.

Comment: Interesting approach, to use the `rect.data().enter()` selection twice.  You wouldn't be able to use that pattern for updates, but it works fine for initialization.

Comment: Hi Lars, I just added the code to my work and it is not working. Do you perhaps know why? http://jsfiddle.net/Sim1/YME9j/13/

Comment: You didn't use the code I wrote -- save the `.enter()` selection before operating on it. http://jsfiddle.net/YME9j/14/

Comment: Hi @AmeliaBR and Lars how can I select these images again to remove some of them based on a condition?? Thanks!

Comment: E.g. `d3.selectAll("image")`.

Comment: Thanks so much @LarsKotthoff, is there any chance you can update the demo to update the position of the image on click (zoom)?

Comment: All you need to do on update is select the `image` instead of appending it and then run the same code to set its position.

Comment: Thanks so much!! Appreciate your quick response!

Comment: Hi @LarsKotthoff, I need an icon on the top-left of each rect as well...could you let me know how to do that? I'm just not sure how to distinguish between the two images. Thanks!

Comment: Assign a different class to each one, e.g. `left` and `right` and then select with `.select("image.left")` etc.